# Number is not a function

Tags: javascript

In my program there is a piece of code structured similar to this:

```
Number.prototype.print = function(){ console.log(this); };
var a = 1,
    b = a + 2

(a - b).print()
```

However, when this gets executed, it throws an error saying "number is not a function". What is happening here and why is this error get thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript semicolons are automatically inserted in most cases. However, seems like the people who developed ES likes to make things more complicated by setting up weird rules for where to put semicolons.

In this case, they decided not to insert semicolon for you, therefore the code becomes this:

```
var a = 1, b = a + 2(a - b).print()
```

As you can see, `2` is interpreted as a function reference, and of course, `2` as a primitive is not a function and thus the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Indeed. Missing just one semicolon, and boom, took me quite some time to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: A good reason to adopt consistent patterns, whether keeping or eliding semicolons. Those like myself who elide, never start a line with `[` or `(` without leading with a semicolon. As such, we're less likely to hit bugs like this.